# How do I split a till receipt using a Regular Expression?

Tags: objective-c, regex, string

The last time I used a regular expression was 2 years ago and even then it wasn't something I considered to be the simplest of things!

Could anybody tell me how I would go about splitting this text into three groups (qty, name, price)?

```
  1 Corn Dog             5.00
  3 Corn Dog            15.00
    @ 5.00
  2 Diet Cola            4.00
    @ 2.00
```

I've attempted it myself following http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html but the symbols are getting overwhelming!  I'm tempted to start doing some funky string manipulation as a plan B.

I'm using Objective-C so I'll probably use NSPredicate to execute the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A handy tool: [Online RegEx Tester](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/regex.htm)

I would start with `^\([:digit]+\)[:space:]*\(.*\)[:space:]\([:digit:]+\.[:digit:]{2}\)`

Remember that different regex compilers have different rules about backslashing `()[]*+|`

Comment: Note my regex wouldn't match the "@ 5.00" lines, but I assume they are just noise since the total price and quantity is on the lines that get matched, so you can compute the each price.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this regex:

```
^\s*(\d+)\x09+([^\x09]+)\x09+\s*(.+)\s*$
```

You can refer to the capturing group as `\1`, `\2`, `\3` if you refer to it the searching part of the regex, and you can refer to the capturing group as as `$1`, `$2`, `$3` if you refer to it the replacing part of the regex.

However, my regex requires you to separate each field with one or more tab characters. I do this because separation with spaces could raise a disambiguity, so the regex would be longer.